# Why didn't a SG team just bring back a Dial Home Device?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could the Stargate Program have stolen a DHD from an uninhabited planet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11218/could-the-stargate-program-have-stolen-a-dhd-from-an-uninhabited-planet)

In the scope of the movie this question probably doesn't work, but during the many seasons (and thus, in-universe years) how come no Stargate team ever bought home a Dial Home Device (DHD) to enable faster dialing without the use of the Cheyenne Mountain computers and local power source?

From watching through all of the seasons of Stargate SG-1, I don't even remember this being mentioned as an idea.

Why didn't one of the SG teams just bring back a Dial Home Device?

Comment: After they discovered the Antarctican stargate they did have a DHD.   As to why they didn't use it I do not know (hence this is a comment, not an answer), maybe they are linked to a specific stargate or maybe they just preferred their own method.  The [Stargate wiki](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/DHD#Earth.27s_DHDs) says it "has since run out of power" which would cover part of their reason for not using it, however that was after it was used by the NID to conduct their own covert missions.

Comment: Bear in mind they had a perfectly adequate solution already, and one with tight integration to the base's security features like the iris and gate room doors, and later a handprint scanner. It also allowed them to automate dialing, and could function as an address book of sorts. They *could* have replaced it, sure, but it's not like the dialing computer didn't have any special features. It's also easier to debug and repair things you built in-house--the ancients don't have a tech support line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off the top of my head, probably because they were unsure of what would happen once the DHD entered the gate. The wormhole is powered by the originating DHD (dialing computer) and so bringing that power source through the worm hole could have unintended consequences to whomever was in transit with it.

Once Earth had interstellar craft they could have brought one back with them that way, but that would then leave the original planet without a DHD. If any future teams had to make an emergency jump to that planet through the stargate (say while playing hide and go seek with some Jaffa), they would be trapped on that planet with no way to contact Earth.

On a more practical note, using a custom dialing computer to control their gate gave the SGC an advantage over every other planet. If ever the DHDs should [ever stop working](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Avenger_2.0) then Earth's gate would still be operational.

Comment: Additionally the dialing computer allowed them a certain level of automation.  They speak a couple of times of cold dialing addresses.  Having the computer dial addresses at a given interval rather than having a person stand there and dial gate addresses over and over is a big plus.  Also the dialing computer would lessen the risk of accidental mis-dials.

Comment: Bear in mind though that we've seen it's possible to interface with a DHD, and I'm sure it would be possible to have the dialling computer dial via the DHD. If that was not possible then even a mechanical button pusher would give great advantage over the existing dialling computer, which could always be kept as a backup.